# How to put json list values underneath each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm trying to put my json file list values underneath each other, now they show up in the html webpage next to each other

I put the json file in a js variable
this is one of the json property lists

```
{
      "title": "super_mario_64",
      "material": "plastic",
      "game_console": [
        "nintendo_ds",
        "nintendo_dsi",
        "nintendo_2D",
        "nintendo_3D(XL)"
      ],
      "color": "grey",
      "operational": true,
      "owners": {
          "name_previous_owner": "unknown",
          "name_current_owner": "donna"
      },
      "image": "images/supermario64.jpg",
    },
```

so the value 'game_console' shows up next to each other and not underneath each other, how can i fix this? (using either css or js?)

i put the json file in a variable called gamedata

i called the json file in js like this:

```
window.onload= () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < gamedata.length; i++){

  var oneGame = gamedata[i];
  console.log(i, oneGame);

  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "game-card";

  var game_console = document.createElement("h3"); 
  game_console.innerText = oneGame.game_console;
  game_console.className = "console-name";

  card.append(game_console);

  document.body.append(card);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be a loop:

```js
var game_console = document.createElement("h3"); 
game_console.innerText = oneGame.game_console;
game_console.className = "console-name";
```

You are setting the inner HTML to `oneGame.game_console` which is joining the entire array. You want each individual console name.

```js
oneGame.game_console.forEach(console => {
  var consoleName = document.createElement("h3");
  consoleName.innerText = console
  consoleName.className = 'console-name';

  gameCard.appendChild(consoleName); // Append each `h3` to the parent `div`
});
```

### Example

```js
const gameData = [{
  "title": "super_mario_64",
  "material": "plastic",
  "game_console": [
    "nintendo_ds",
    "nintendo_dsi",
    "nintendo_2D",
    "nintendo_3D(XL)"
  ],
  "color": "grey",
  "operational": true,
  "owners": {
    "name_previous_owner": "unknown",
    "name_current_owner": "donna"
  },
  "image": "images/supermario64.jpg",
}];

const gameCards = document.querySelector('.game-cards');

gameData.forEach((oneGame, index) => {
  const gameCard = document.createElement('div');
  gameCard.className = 'game-card';
  
  const gameTitle = document.createElement('h2');
  gameTitle.innerText = oneGame.title
  gameTitle.className = 'game-title';
  gameCard.appendChild(gameTitle);
  
  oneGame.game_console.forEach(console => {
    const consoleName = document.createElement('h3');
    consoleName.innerText = console
    consoleName.className = 'console-name';
    gameCard.appendChild(consoleName);
  });

  gameCards.appendChild(gameCard);
});
```

```html
<div class="game-cards"></div>
```